Change table size in jspdf
I want to make the table as same as this image. I'm facing issue while changing the table width as per my choice. I also tried looking at the documentation but it doesn't help much.
`
var config = {
  cellWidth: 100,
  autoSize: true,
  printHeaders: true,
}
autoTable(doc, {
  head: header,
  body: data,
  startY: 80,
  showHead: "never",
  showFoot: "never",

  tableWidth: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(),
  margin: { left: 0 },
});

const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
if (formData.course === 'B.tech') {

  var data = [{ Year: '1', Onetimefee: '500', TuitionFee: '160' },
  { Year: '2', Onetimefee: '-', TuitionFee: '160' }
  ];

  doc.text(20, 20, 'Ref-A101');
  doc.text(20, 30, `Name: ${formData.name}`);
  doc.text(20, 40, `Course: ${formData.course}`);
  doc.text(20, 50, `Date of Offer (current date): ${currentDate}`);
  doc.text(20, 60, `Fee Structure:`);
  doc.setTableHeaderRow(10);
  doc.setTableHeaderRow(10);
  doc.table(20, 70, data, header, config);


} else if (formData.course === 'M.tech') {

  var data = [{ Year: '1', Onetimefee: '600', TuitionFee: '260' },
  { Year: '2', Onetimefee: '-', TuitionFee: '260' }
  ];

  doc.text(20, 20, 'Ref-B101');
  doc.text(20, 30, `Name: ${formData.name}`);
  doc.text(20, 40, `Course: ${formData.course}`);
  doc.text(20, 50, `Date of Offer (current date): ${currentDate}`);
  doc.text(20, 60, `Fee Structure:`);
  doc.table(20, 70, data, header, config);

}

doc.save(`${formData.name}_${formData.course}_Offer.pdf`);

);
}
export default App;
`
This is my image
